# Divide elements of a list by integer with list comprehension: index out of range

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension, index-error

I am trying to divide all the elements of a list filled with integers by another integer (functionality like in numpy arrays) by list comprehension, like so:

```
results = 300 * [0]
for i in range(100):
    for j in range(300):
        results[j] += random.randrange(0,300)
average_results = [results[x] / 100 for x in results]
```

However, if I run this in Python, it throws an

```
IndexError: list index out of range
```

I have worked around this by using a regular for loop:

```
average_results = []
for x in results:
    average_results.append(x/100)
```

which works like a charm.

However, in my mind the two approaches should yield the same results, so I am totally stunted as to why it does not work.

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is with:

```
  [results[x] / 100 for x in results]
```

Here you are iterating over **values** in the results list (`for x in results`). And then for each of them trying to access the element with this index.
What you rather meant was:

```
 [x / 100 for x in results]
```

In other words - the "for ... in ..." part of list comprehension works with values in the list, not their indices.

*BTW*, your `[x / 100 for x in results]` won't give you an average of all values. It will "only" take each of them and divide by 100.

Comment: They sum `randint(0, 300)` a hundred times,  the average of that is taken.

Comment: Thank you! Concise, clear and helpful. I of course meant x / 300. Edited.

Answer (score 1):

This is the equivalent list comprehension to your loop:

```
average_results = [x / 100 for x in results]
```

`x` is already the value form `results`. Don't index again into it with `results[x]`.

Answer (score 1):

Your array is filled with random integer values, ranging from 0 to 29999. In your list comprehension you make, as far as I can see, a mistake here:

```
results[x]
```

`x` is already the value in the array, i.e. the random integer. You get the `IndexError` because `results[29999]` is, for example, one of the possible calls there.

What you want instead is to not use `x` as an index:

```
average_results = [x / 100 for x in results]
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use one of these at the end:

```
1. average_results = [results[x] / 100 for x in range(len(results))]
2. average_results = [x / 100 for x in results]
```

the problem is you're trying to access to an index that does not exist (x is the value there not the index)

Answer (score -1):

This should be straight forward and possible.

```
In [1]: results = 10 * [10]

In [2]: [_/10 for _ in results]
Out[2]: [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
```